# Is there a library in php to handle and compress mp3 files in php..?

Tags: php, mp3, compression

Is there anyway in php to handle i.e compress a mp3 file using php...? Is there any library out there like ZZIPlib library (To handle .ZIP files)...?

Thanks for your suggestions...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there are any libraries that will let you compress MP3s (I presume you're talking about generating an MP3 from a WAV/AIFF, etc. file?)

As such, it would probably make more sense to simply shell escape out (using [exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) and [escapeshellarg](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) if relevant) and use standard command line utils such as [lame](http://lame.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Ni... I am not converting from other formats to MP3.. I am trying to convert the bitrate of a given mp3 file.... 
Just checking whether it's possible.....

Comment: I'd say using the command line tools would still be the best way to go.

Comment: the problem is the requirement for the software does not allow for this approach.. all i get is a zip file of folder containing mp3 files.. and i have to unzip the file .... create a copy of each song.... change the bitrate of the copy and then create two seperate xml playlists.. one for the normal bitrate and the other for the lower bitrate.... All this using php....

Comment: In that case PHP simply isn't an appropriate tool for what you're trying to achieve.